# Gulp TsLint & Mocha report file

Tags: gulp, mocha.js, tslint

I can use TSLint to check the syntax errors of my TypeScript files but I cannot generate a report file with the errors, and I have the same problem with mocha: I run the tests but I cannot generate a file report.

I'm using gulp tasks.

```
gulp.task('tslint', 'Lints all TypeScript source files', function(){
return gulp.src(tsFilesGlob)
.pipe(tslint())
.pipe(tslint.report('verbose'));
});


gulp.task('test', 'Runs the Mocha test specs', ['build'], function () {
return gulp.src('build/test/**/*.js')
    .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'xunit'}));
});
```

Comment: Could you add more details? Are you seeing certain errors?

Comment: @edit: I edited my question with my gulp tasks.